# How to switch active class on Bootstrap nav tabs from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a webpage where I have a set of nav tabs on the home page that have a link to where the user can click to obtain more information. I want the site to then to to the correct nav tab on another page with the additional information as per the link they clicked. Here is the link to the github repo:

https://github.com/rise-and-shane93/Clean-Sweep-Products-Current

Comment: So you want to set the tabs depending on which page the client has been redirect to but scroll to a specific point in the page? If so then I suggest you use a hash in the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to add a # fragment identifier to the URL of the page I'm calling with the tab name, like https://page.html#tab1 . Then, in your called page, on document ready,  you can search the URL for the #tab1 and if it's present, open tab1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    hashValue = window.location.hash;
    if(hashValue != undefined && hashValue == "#tab1"){
        $("#tab1").show();
    }   
});
```